# Inheritance in Python: does a derived class "copy" or "refer to" methods in its base class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Executing the following code in Python will print a `True` and a `False`.

```
class Foo:
    attr = 42

    def func(self):
        print "Hello"

class Foo2(Foo):
    pass

foo = Foo()
foo2 = Foo2()

print foo.attr is foo2.attr
print foo.func is foo2.func
```

I understand why the first print statement results in `True` (it's evaluated to `print 42 is 42`), but do not understand why the second statement prints `False`.

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), it is said

> if a requested attribute is not found in the class, the search
>   proceeds to look in the base class

This indicates that there is only one copy of the attribute (`func` in this case), and the derived class just refers to the copy in the base class. Therefore I expect `foo`'s `func` is the same as `foo2`'s `func`.

I also used [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) to visualize the execution of the code. It shows only one `func` was created:

[image]

So, could someone explain why `foo.func` isn't `foo2.func`?

PS: [a similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236060/inheritance-is-code-from-superclass-virtually-copied-to-subclass-or-is-it-r) was asked for Java, and the answer is derived class will "refer to" methods in the base class.

Comment: Because functions are descriptors, which create bound methods on attribute lookup.

Comment: Try `print Foo.func is Foo2.func`

Comment: Look at `repr(foo.func)` and `repr(foo2.func)`. They are different…

Comment: In the case of `attr`, you're just doing `42 is 42` which is `True` but isn't very interesting.  In the `func` case, you're comparing two bound methods.  These are methods whose `self` has been bound.  In one case `self` is `foo` and in the other case `self` is `foo2`.  So they aren't the same, and in fact could behave differently when called if `func` did something with `self`.

Comment: @Phydeaux In Python 2 `Foo.func` isn't `Foo2.func`, while in Python 3 `Foo.func` is `Foo2.func`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `foo` and `foo2` are two different instances of the class and subclass.  Even though the `func` really is the same reference between `Foo` and `Foo2`, once you instantiate the classes *bound methods* are created based on these two *different* instances, so the memory address is no longer the same and are not the same object, even though they do exactly the same thing:

```
>>> foo = Foo()             
>>> foo2 = Foo2()               
>>> foo.func

<bound method Foo.func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x072623D0>>
>>> foo2.func

<bound method Foo.func of <__main__.Foo2 object at 0x07262AD0>>  # notice the different object
```

Worth noting if you change `Foo.func`, `Foo2.func` reference will also change.  However if you change `Foo2.func`, `Foo.func` will not be changed:

```
>>> Foo2.func

<function Foo.func at 0x0726B780>
>>> Foo.func

<function Foo.func at 0x0726B780>
>>> Foo.func = lambda: print("I'm new!")

>>> Foo.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B738>
>>> Foo2.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B738>  # Follows the same reference
>>> Foo2.func = lambda: print("Some other func")

>>> Foo2.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B780>  # New function
>>> Foo.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B738>  # unchanged.
```

And then if you add new methods to `Foo`, `Foo2` will also pick it up automatically:

```
>>> Foo.func2 = lambda: print('hey!')

>>> Foo2.func2

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B7C8>
```

But once you overwrites the existing reference of the inherited `Foo.func`, even if you reassign `Foo.func`, `Foo2.func` will no longer hold the same reference:

```
>>> Foo.func = lambda: print("I'm renewed!")

>>> Foo.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B738>  # newly assigned object
>>> Foo2.func

<function <lambda> at 0x0726B780>  # Reference remains as before
```

Comment: This answer is only applicable to Python 3.
For Python 2, `foo2.func` will be `<bound method Foo2.func of <__main__.Foo2 instance at 0x1027f47a0>>`

Comment: Even if two instances are of the **same** class, a method of one instance has a different address than the corresponding method of the other instance.

`>>> a = Foo()`

`>>> b = Foo()`

`>>> a.func`

`<bound method Foo.func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x1083bf6d8>>`

`>>> b.func`

`<bound method Foo.func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x1083bfe10>>`

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say here... I mean the bound method is definitely separate per instance regardless of class, are you just agreeing?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to add an example of another case: two instances of the same class (instead of one instance of base class and one instance of derived class).